# Make one EditText row clickable and not editable Android

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I'm showing a list of items on the activity and I'm using an ArrayAdapter so I can only have a TextView/EditText in my xml. But I want to be able to edit the text and save that somehow. Right now... I can only edit but since I have no buttons, I can't save the content. Can I make one row from the list to be uneditable but clickable? To simulate the action of a button?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_edit_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#035E7B"
    />
```

Something like :

Row1Editable

Row2Editable

Row3Editable

ClickHere to save your edits

```
    public class SingleListItem extends ListActivity {
    SweetsXmlController controller;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_list_item);
        controller = new SweetsXmlController();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int position = intent.getIntExtra("position", 1);
        String[] mTestArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sections);
        Sweet toShow = controller.getSweetByPosition(position, mTestArray);

        ArrayList<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
        res.add(toShow.getName());
        res.add("$" + toShow.getPrice());
        res.add(toShow.getDescription());
        res.add(toShow.getCalories() + "kcal");res.add("Click here to save your changes!");

        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.my_edit_text);
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                Log.d("HAAAAAAAAAAAAH", "Trying to MOVE TO NEXT ITEM ");
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,
                R.layout.activity_single_list_item,
                res);
        setListAdapter(adapter);



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write a custom adapter for this - have a look at http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html. In the adapter's getView() method, you can use the EditText.setEnabled(boolean) method to toggle whether it is editable or not.

Also, if all you need is a single button, it would be easier to have a separate listview + a button in your layout.

Comment: You can't separate them cause I'd rathern ot complicate myself using a custom adapter.

Comment: If you want to add custom behaviour to certain members of a listview, you will need a custom adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this method below:

```
EditText myEditTextField = new EditText(this);

myEditTextField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});
```

After text changed, just save the output in textView.

Comment: I dont understand how I'd apply this to my problem

Comment: Just add textChngedListener to the editTextField, and whenever user changes some content in the text, call a function that saves user's data on each letter changing (or you can use countDownTimer to wait for 1 or 2 seconds to save the user data)

Comment: how will the program know that editText is the one I have in my activity? By this?

Comment: I am assuming that you have given particular id and name to your edit text. so just with name, you can add textchangelistener

Comment: This doesn't work cause I'm extending a ListActivity, it expects for me to have a list... but I give an EditText. It keeps crashing with android.widget.EditText cannot be cast to android.widget.ListView

Comment: Can you provide the codes related to it? Activity in which you extended ListActivity

Comment: I added the class and the current exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128541/discussion-between-swr7der-and-mocktheduck).